# FirebaseAnalytics logEvent() causes OOM

Tags: android, firebase, analytics

I'm tracking how the user is navigating inside my application with Firebase like so:

```
    43. FirebaseAnalytics mTracker = MyApplication.getDefaultTracker();
    44. Bundle payload = new Bundle();
    45. payload.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, "page");
    46. mTracker.logEvent("Navigation", payload);
```

And once in a while I get OOM Exception with this stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzac.zzay(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzac.zzay(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzac.zzay(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.logEvent(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown Source)
       at com.a.b.c.trackNavigation(SoudfaTracker.java:46)
       at com.a.b.c.ProfileFragment.init(ProfileFragment.java:167)
       at com.a.b.c.ProfileFragment_.onViewChanged(ProfileFragment_.java:190)
       at org.androidannotations.api.view.OnViewChangedNotifier.notifyViewChanged(OnViewChangedNotifier.java:41)
       at com.soudfa.Fragments.Profile.ProfileFragment_.onViewCreated(ProfileFragment_.java:104)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

I'm running `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.2'`
Has anyone tried this?

Comment: From the information in your post it looks like your app is running out of memory when creating a worker thread (Firebase Analytics will create one worker thread to process your events). Creating a thread does consume some memory (the stack must be pre-allocated) but generally doesn't need huge amount of memory. How much free memory you have left in your app? By default (unless you request huge heap) the app can allocate 64MB of memory before java starts throwing OOM.

Comment: Very useful! This is probably the issue have no idea how to see the Ram usage while it is live